# unable to get div width after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a following structure

```
<div id="item">
   <div id="template">
      <div id="Div1">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<style>
    #template {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background: #99ff66;
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    #Div1 {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: black;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-top:5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

my append operation like this

```
var container = this._id;
var templateContainer = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "template_group_", container);
var cloneNode = $("#item").clone();
$(cloneNode).attr("#item" + '_' + "left");
var $cloneNode = $(cloneNode);
$cloneNode.css("position", "absolute");
$cloneNode.css("display", "block").appendTo($(templateContainer));
var c = $("#item_left").width();// here i am getting null
$(templateContainer).appendTo('#' + container);
var d = $("#item_left").width(); // here i am getting 0
var top = 10;
$cloneNode.css("top", top).css('cursor', 'pointer');
var a = $("#item" + '_' + "left").width(); // here i am getting 0
```

here i didn't get the width of the div.. 
while append the div i unable to get the width but 
after append if i click or drag that div(item_left) i get the exact width.but, how can i get the width of the div in first time(after append)?

Comment: could you please share jsfiddle link with your problem statement

Comment: @AkbarBasha please stop editing this. I have fixed it for you and had to rollback to it twice after you edited in more formatting errors.

Comment: what is `this._id` show full function and there are some syntax mistakes existed in your code.

Comment: Hi Venkata Panga this._id is the container is which i append template_group

Answer (score 0):

To show what's going on I have added a div with id = "myContainer" to your HTML, so we can append the new elements to that div:

```
<div id="myContainer"></div>
```

Now we set `var container` to that id (maybe you have some other code to get the id you want append to):

```
var container = "myContainer"
```

In your second line you create a new div with `$("<div></div>")`. That returns a jQuery-object so let's name the variable `$templateContainer` to clarify. Then you want to set the id-attribute to `template_group_myContainer` so you have to use a `+` instead of a comma inside `.attr()`. So the second line must be:

```
var $templateContainer = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "template_group_" + container);
```

In third line you clone `$("#item")`. It returns a jQuery-object so name the variable `$cloneNode` to clarify. In fourth line you want to set the id of the clone to `item_left`, but you miss the attribute-name `id`, and the `#` in front of the name is incorrect here. Also you can do both in one line by chaining, so line 3 and 4 together:

```
var $cloneNode = $("#item").clone().attr('id', "item_left");
```

Since we have already a jQuery-object `$cloneNode` we don't need to do it again: remove line 5 completely. In line 7 you append the clone to `$templateContainer`. Since that is already a jQuery there's no need to do `$()` again, line 7 should look like:

```
$cloneNode.css("display", "block").appendTo($templateContainer);
```

Now `$cloneNode` is appended to `$templateContainer`, but `$templateContainer` itself (and all whats inside it) is not appended anywhere at this moment. Thats why in line 8 `var c` absolutely correct 
is null: elements that are not in the DOM simply have no width.

In line 9 you append `$templateContainer` (and all whats in it) to `#myContainer`. `$templateContainer` is already jQuery so no `$()` again and line 9 becomes:

```
$templateContainer.appendTo('#' + container);
```

From that moment on `$templateContainer` and all elements in it have a width, and after correcting the code `var d / var a` in line 10 / 13 get the right value (36).

[**DEMO**, use console](http://jsfiddle.net/op7b9kyw/8/).

BTW, In your code `$("#item_left")` and `$("#item" + '_' + "left")` gets the same element as `var $cloneNode` has already, its better to use the var instead of repeating the `$()` again and again.